# Android Studio to React Native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have one app published on Google play store which was developed in android studio but now I want to take my app from android studio to react native.

So can i publish my react native updated version to playstore (Not Android Studio Code)

Is it possible?
If yes then how to publish app via custom android studio key and is there any issue with Google play store ore something like that via publish android studio to react native app.

Answer (score 0):

yes, please keep in mind package name should be same and version code and version name incremented by one from previous version.

After Completed the app in react native you can change version code and version name in app/build.gradle file

```
  defaultConfig {
    .....
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

and package name can change from package.json and AndroidManifest file